# Eclipse-New Project Wizard -default component not found---how to configure?

Tags: android, eclipse, configuration

I am using Eclipse Platform-3.7.2,ubuntu 12.04,java-"1.6.0_24" OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.5)

I installed Android platform & packages using Android SDK Manager. I installed ADT plugin from android site in Eclipse,but after its restarts,not giving any message like "Welcome to Android Development" to seelect existing SDKs path.

I gone to New-->Project-->New project wizard,but window show only "General" & "CVS" option.In General-->Project only.

I am wondering where gone my other project component,e.g. Java,Latex etc. which comes default with Eclipse.
I used android-sdk for [Processing](http://processing.org/),it has Android SDk & AVD manager option.

what should i do now to run Android/java project in eclipse.

I also have installed sun java in my machine,but i want OpenJdk to be default to run other softwares

Comment: did you give path of your `android-sdk` in Eclipse ?

Comment: No Eclipse never asked for that....,& when i am going to install again ADT plugin,it says that they are already installed

Comment: Go ot `Windows` > `Preferences` > Android > add Path ofyour sdk there.

Comment: if you installed adt correctly, your android project will be in new->project->others->android folder create android application project

Comment: @M Mohsin Naeem,windows>preferences> nothing like "Android".except,General,help,install...i checked each option but not found anything like Android/Java

Comment: @kumaand I installed ADT plugin correctly,during & after installation,it never gives any error.I also go for new->project->others,but wizard dont have Android option

Comment: you installed adt know? you have option of avd manager and sdk manager icon in top left of eclipse window. If it is you have to place sdk location in preference and create project

Comment: @kumaand. No i can't find AVD/SDk manager icon on top in Eclipse,but in Processing software they have.Is it like that they are taken by processing.If this is true.what should i do?

Comment: you have not installed adt plugin in eclipse yet, follow these steps http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

Comment: @kumaand,I already installed(ADT plugin),i.e. Android DDMS,Developement Tools,Hierarchy Viwer,Native Development tools,Traceview which can be viewd in "Eclipse Platform Installatiion Details" wizard,under "installed software" panel

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue after I did a Help-->Check For Updates and installed the updates. To revert and get back the normal options in the wizard, I had to do the following.

Help --> Install New Software
Click on the "already installed" link in the window.
Eclipse Platform Installation Details window opens. Switch to Installation History tab.
You will see current installation and another datetime-stamped line item. 
Selected the immediate item under the current installation and click revert.

These steps above got me back the environment.

Something is broken in Check for Updates option in eclipse. I learned my lesson to stay away from it atleast for now.